# Why Kotlin throws an exception in a very simple piece of code?

Tags: android, exception, kotlin

- There are an **update** in the end of the question. Now I've got to turn on and turn off the error with one line change in a tiny project with all code transcribed below.
- The **answer** of [Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov%20thes) is brilliant. Check in the end of the question. it's an amazing and unknown feature of *Android Studio* environment.

I've found a very kinky error in *Kotlin* using updated *Android 3.4.2*.

First I've run my test code in my computer (not *Android*) using main modules in any kotlin file in my only module. It always works for me, but it has started to give an error that I comment below and then another error that don't allow to run the main module anymore.

Searching in `Stack Overflow`, one user as claimed that the last described error ends when one uses `test` files under `java` folder (Not `Android test` files)

However is has  continued to give the first error, which I commented above, which I managed to reduce to the following schematic example:

```
class Cl(
  var a:Int=0
)
var vCl = arrayListOf<Cl>()
```

And the main module is:

```
fun main(){
    println("start")
    vCl.clear()  // error points to this line
    println("ok")
}
```

I  just point to `fun main()` line in *test* file and click the green icon.

The error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Suddenly the error stops when I've changed one global statement from one file to another file (in the top part, outside any class or function).

```
var timings = TimingLogger("MyTag", "Your")
```

It's crazy. I'm freaking out!

**Update:**
**=======**

I've made `newerror`, a new tiny project with one module to reproduce the error decribed in this question. Below is the complete code:

**Gradle**: No change after project creation.

**AndroidManifest.xml**: No change after project creation.

**activity_main.xml**: It is bare bone because all my views are dinamically created:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=
          "br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.myerror.MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

The **MainActivity.kt** code:

```
package br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.myerror

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

The **compiler.kt** code

```
package br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.myerror

import android.util.TimingLogger
var timings = TimingLogger("MyTag", "Your")
class Cl(
    var a:Int=0
)
var vCl = arrayListOf<Cl>()
```

Finally the **test.kt** code:

```
package br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.myerror

fun main(){
    println("start")
    vCl.clear()
    println("ok")
}
```

The complete error message when I run *test.kt* code in my computer (not in Android):

```
start
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.myerror.TestKt.main(test.kt:5)
    at br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.myerror.TestKt.main(test.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.util.TimingLogger.<init>(TimingLogger.java:59)
    at br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.myerror
              .CompilerKt.<clinit>(compiler.kt:5)
    ... 2 more
```

And, again, if I put the below declaration inside **MainActivity.kt** and run the *test.kt* again in my computer ...

```
var timings = TimingLogger("MyTag", "Your")
```

... and the error is gone!

```
start
ok
```

For those who want to see to believe:

[image: crazy bug]

**Conclusion**: Now I know how to avoid this crazy error, but I don't understand why it works! Ih theory, the source file that I use to make my declarations should be interchangeable, because all files are in the same module!

---

```
                              Solution of puzzle
```

---

[Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov%20thes) has hit the nail on the head!

I've researched a little bit more and I've found that *Android Studio* only executes the declarations in a file if any variable of the scope was used in a computer test.

When

```
var timings = TimingLogger("MyTag", "Your")
```

is inside `MainActivity.kt`, no error is shown.

After I put in this file the following code:

```
open class Fool(val a:Int=5){
   init { println("fool") }
} 

class SuperFool(a:Int=8):Fool(a) {
  init { println("what a big fool") }
}
var v = SuperFool()
```

When I put  `println(v.a)` my code in *test.kt* becomes:

```
package br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.myerror

fun main(){
    println("start")
    println(v.a)   // new line
    vCl.clear()    
    println("ok")
}
```

And it gives the same error than before! Take out this line and no error again!

The solution is if one has any declaration of some variable in an *Android* class in your projet you MUST use `lateinit` and just initializate in other point of code that will not run in test execution.

In this case one can do

```
lateinit var timings:TimingLogger
```

And put the initialization in other place (inside `onCreate` in `MainActivity` class, for instance. In my case, immediately before the 1st. call `addSplit`, one of the methods from `TimingLogger` class

```
timings = TimingLogger("MyTag", "Your")
```

Now my test code gently prints

```
start
fool
what a big fool
ok
```

Comment: how do you are instantiating vDispFu ?

Comment: Sorry, another typo. The simplification uses `vCl`.

Comment: I've corrected it.

Comment: I've just tried this in my test file, it passed. you put them in the same file or not?

Comment: No, I've placed the declaration in normal Kotlin file (in the same folder of `mainActivity.kt` source file)  and the test code in a test Kotlin file, under `(test)` folder. Both under `java` folder.  Unfortunately it's an intermitent error. Now it is ok. Remember that how it's the same module all global declarations are shareable.

Comment: You must share detail your code occur error.

Comment: Ok, I've discovered a pattern.

Comment: I've made an update in the end of  my question. I go on researching my problem.

Comment: maybe post full code here?

Comment: Oh, it's huge. I will make it better. I will make now a very tiny project to reproduce this error.

Comment: I got it. I wil make a new update!

Comment: It's under **Update 2** in the end of the question. I 've got to turn on and off the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Kotlin; you can't just use Android classes in code running directly on your computer and not in an emulator, because the versions in the standard jar will crash on first use. They are just there to provide class files with the same names and method signatures as will exist on the device, so that your code can compile (not run!).

Use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/) to get a usable-for-JVM-tests version of the Android library.

> if I put the below declaration inside MainActivity.kt and run the test.kt again in my computer

Then your test doesn't use any Android classes (see below for details).

> It is worth remembering that, within the same module, all declarations, regardless of what file they are in, are executed.

That's wrong. What happens with top-level `val`/`var`/`fun` declarations in Kotlin is that they get wrapped into a single class for each file, so your code works like this:

```
// compiler.kt
package br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.myerror

object CompilerKt { // you can actually see the name in the stack trace
    var timings = TimingLogger("MyTag", "Your")
    val vCl = arrayListOf<Cl>()
}

class Cl(
    var a:Int=0
)

// test.kt
package br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.myerror

object TestKt {
    fun main(){
        println("start")
        CompilerKt.vCl.clear()
        println("ok")
    }
}
```

So calling `TestKt.main()` forces loading and initialization of `CompilerKt` because you reference `vCl` there. This includes calling the constructor `TimingLogger("MyTag", "Your")` which thrown an exception when the stub library is used.

Calling `TestKt.main()` does *not* load `MainActivity` (which you can confirm by adding some print to that file), so if you move `var timings` there, nothing in the stub library gets called.

Comment: I know this, but it's just a declaration and an initialization. of a variable, it's not a real usage, because I don't use `timingLogger` in my test.  And when I simply change the declaration to another source file, my tiny demo project works perfectly (and the original, much larger, too). It is worth remembering that, within the same module, all declarations, regardless of what file they are in, are executed.

Comment: 1. Look at the error trace: the exception is thrown in the constructor `at android.util.TimingLogger.<init>(TimingLogger.java:59)`. This constructor is exactly what's called by `TimingLogger("MyTag", "Your")`.

Comment: 2. "It is worth remembering that, within the same module, all declarations, regardless of what file they are in, are executed." No, they aren't. Just replace `TimingLogger` with your own class which prints something in constructor and you'll see it gets printed in your current failing case and doesn't get printed in the successful case.

Comment: I've extended the answer.

Comment: Wow! It's crazy. You are right. I made the following test. 
I put in `MainActivity` the following code  `open class Fool(val a:Int=5){
init {println("fool") }} class SuperFool(a:Int=8):Fool(a){init {println("what a big fool")}}`. When I put  `println(v.a)` in `compiler.kt` has an error. Take out and no error! It is as if Android Studio only executes the declarations in a file if any variable of the scope was used.

Comment: The solution is use `lateinit` in `TimingLogger`.

Comment: I will write an new update in my question. It's bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a an quote on your first line.

Comment: It's just a typo when I've changed the start message. It's not a real error in my code. The program would not even run with this error.